# Editing a database in PHP with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, updates, crud

Working my way though Creating, Reading, Updating & Deleting (CRUD) information from a database I have done C,R & D but for some reason I can not update.
What am trying to do:
Edit a categorizes title
My Results:
when clicking edit in the table of the cat title I want to change I can get the cat title to echo into a form, where it can be changed then when i try and change the cat title, click update the form goes away as I wanted but the cat title stays the same.
as well am not getting any query errors
What should I look for when debugging code that has no errors?
Can someone see my problem?

```
 if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {

  $cat_id = $_GET['edit'];

include "includes/update.php";

}    
     ?>

       <form action="categories.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="cat_title">Edit Category</label>

<?php 
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $cat_id = $_GET['edit'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id = $cat_id ";
    $select_categories_id = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories_id)) {
    $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
    $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];
    ?>
    <input value="<?php if(isset($cat_title)){echo $cat_title;} ?>" class="form-control" type="text" name="cat_title">

<?php
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['edit_category'])){
    $edit_cat_title = $_POST['cat_title'];

    $query = "UPDATE FROM categories SET cat_title = '{$edit_cat_title}' WHERE cat_id = {$cat_id} ";
    $edit_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if (!$edit_query) {
        die(mysqli_error($edit_query));
    }

}

 ?>
   </div>
 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="edit_category" value="Edit Category">     
   </form>
```

Comment: Hi Ste. You need to add details to your question to get help on SO. First is you need to tell us what your results are and what you are expecting. Also if you can use the least amount of code to identify the issue along with cleaning up your code indenting will give your question a much better chance of getting answered.

Comment: Hey @Shawn thanks buddy I will keep this in my mind for the future and make some changes to this post

Comment: have you turned on PHP error reporting?

Comment: Yes, thanks buddy @Martin

Comment: so PHP error reporting doesn't give you any errors at all?

Comment: after you set `$query`, do `var_dump($query)` , what does it show you?

Comment: @Martin it returns  string(42) "SELECT * FROM catagories WHERE cat_id = 5 "

Comment: So that means `$_POST['edit_category']` is never set. So you need to double check why this is never set. Does this form field have the correct name? Does this form field get given a valid value?

Comment: Yes nothing comes up for the update query... double slaps forehead

Comment: right, so see my comment above re: $_POST value is never set.

Comment: The names is the same 'edit_category' and I set the value to the same as the name and am still not getting a result @Martin

Comment: ok so print `var_dump($_POST);` near the top of your page and  resubmit your form, What do you see?

Comment: It prints the value array(0) { }

Comment: ok so your post values are not being populated. You can try and add the `enctype` field to your form, see my answer (below) for details. does this now populate the `$_POST` array with data when ylu submit the form?

Comment: also what does `include "includes/update.php"` do? Does it remove POST values?

Comment: update.php is where the categorizes form sits till edit is clicked then it includes it into categorizes.php. am just working my way though your answer will give you the results soo n

Answer (score 1):

In the following line you have a small error:

```
$query = "UPDATE FROM categories SET cat_title = '{$edit_cat_title}' WHERE cat_id = {$cat_id} ";
```

You need to remove the "FROM" in there, will look like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE categories SET cat_title = '{$edit_cat_title}' WHERE cat_id = {$cat_id} ";
```

and it should work as expected.

Comment: FROM has been removed but still not updating

Answer (score 0):

you're calling the update query with

```
$query = "UPDATE FROM categories SET cat_title = '{$edit_cat_title}' WHERE cat_id = {$cat_id} ";
```

where $cat_id probably is not set, 
once to get this value you're using an if condition

```
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $cat_id = $_GET['edit'];
```

where the $_GET[ 'edit' ] can be empty, and the next error is to overwrite the $cat_id variable in a loop:  $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];

Comment: Am not sure what am suppose to do, I have moved the $cat_id to                          if(isset($_POST['edit_category'])){
    $edit_cat_title = $_POST['cat_title'];
    $cat_id = $_GET['edit'];
     and am not getting anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
       $cat_id = $_GET['edit'];
       include "includes/update.php";
      }    
     ?>

       <form action="categories.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="cat_title">Edit Category</label>

<?php 
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $cat_id = $_GET['edit'];

}

if(isset($_POST['edit_category'])){
    $edit_cat_title = $_POST['cat_title'];

    $query = "UPDATE FROM categories SET cat_title = '{$edit_cat_title}' WHERE cat_id = {$cat_id} ";
    $edit_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if (!$edit_query) {
        die(mysqli_error($edit_query));
    }

}
```

- Delete that `FROM`, it should be `UPDATE categories SET ...`
- You realise that `$edit_cat_title` is from a POST value, but `$cat_id` is from a GET value, but your form (as far as I can see) has an `action` value of `action = "categories.php"` which will contain ***NO GET VARIABLES***.
- Add the property `enctype` to your `<form>` such as:

  ```
   <form ... enctype='multipart/form-data' ... >
  ```

To be honest this last point is good practise but I'd be surprised if that was why your POST data was not being populated.

**Possible solutions:**

1) Use `$_REQUEST['cat_id']` and insert the cat_id as a POSTed field in your form, so it can use variables given by either `$_POST` or `$_GET` *[or `$_COOKIE`]*.

2) change your action to goto : `action ="categories.php?edit=XXX"` to submit the form to an address with a valid GET value as required.

3) Use sessions to hold data from previous pages (such as `cat_id`). This is my prefered option.

### Extra

From question comments it becomes clear that the part `if isset($_POST['edit_category'])` is never `true`, so this means that your form is incorrect -- either you have not got a form field named `name='edit_cateogry'` or your form field is never filled in, or never sent with the form (perhaps the input is placed after the `</form>` form closing tag?

Anyhow, your issue is that your $_POST value you are looking for is never set.